# How do i sum consecutively the 4th element of a list of lists (python)

Tags: python

I have this:

```
lst=[['Lisboa', 36.751510873830824, 204.31859739607566, '3'],
    ['Madrid', 520.8624708804804, 392.9722807116641, '2'],
    ['Copenhaga', 1971.3230985689115, 2086.416520356296, '5'],
    ['Berlin', 2046.6589661942558, 1735.7426148990855, '4']]
```

and want to receive this:

```
[['Lisboa', 36.751510873830824, 204.31859739607566, '3'],
['Madrid', 520.8624708804804, 392.9722807116641, '5'],
['Copenhaga', 1971.3230985689115, 2086.416520356296, '10'],
['Berlin', 2046.6589661942558, 1735.7426148990855, '14']]
```

Hope to get some help here!!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Your question is attracting downvotes, and close votes, because it doesn't meet the guidelines at [ask].

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is not clear whether or not you need *** around the initial value of 3.  If these were a failed attempt to bold the numbers, and you need the number in string format, then try:

```
cumsum = 0
for i in lst:
    cumsum += int(i[3])
    i[3] = str(cumsum)

>>> lst
[['Lisboa', 36.751510873830824, 204.31859739607566, '3'],
 ['Madrid', 520.8624708804804, 392.9722807116641, '5'],
 ['Copenhaga', 1971.3230985689115, 2086.416520356296, '10'],
 ['Berlin', 2046.6589661942558, 1735.7426148990855, '14']]
```

Comment: Pretty sure the asterisks were a failed attempt to make the font within the code bold.

Comment: Other than spite, not sure for the reason for the down vote since it answered the OP's question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a questionable pattern probably, but:

```
 summed = 0
 for inner_list in outer_list:
      summed += inner_list[3]
      inner_list[3] = summed
```

If you want to keep the strings for some reason:

```
 summed = 0
 for inner_list in outer_list:
      summed += int(inner_list[3])
      inner_list[3] = str(summed)
```

Comment: Sorry, why the down vote?

Comment: I'm only guessing, but this question is in the close vote queue, because it doesn't meet the guidelines (That's how I came across it).   The "accepted" thing to do with questions that don't meet the guidelines is flag them, not answer them.  This seems unhelpful to me, but it's how it works - you may not know that.   Irritated close vote queue reviewers may downvote your answer because it encourages bad questions.    That's not officially accepted either, but it happens. You can read the controversy about this at meta.stackoverflow.com if you're interested.   HTH you understand.